# I do shock. I was praised by my teacher

Tags: word-usage, grammar

He was being praised by his teacher.

> "**I *do* shock.** I was praised by my teacher." he told me.

I was surprised.
I was shock.

Can he use "do" or is should be "was"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Do shock" is not idiomatic.  Instead, you *get* (or *receive*) a **shock**, or you *are* **shocked**.

> Mary **got a shock** when her teacher praised her
>   Mary **was shocked** when her teacher praised her
>
> I **got a shock** when I heard that my neighbor had died.
>   I **was shocked** to hear that my neighbor had died.

It's much the same as "surprise".

> Mary **got a surprise** when she saw her children cleaning up without being asked.
>   Mary **was surprised** to see her children cleaning up without being asked.

(Edit) Nowadays, it's common to hear people say they were *shocked* by some event when they mean they were merely *surprised*.  To *get a shock* is more extreme, as if you literally touched an electrical wire.

Comment: Note that the "got a ..." construction may be restricted to AmE; it certainly sounds strange to me as a BrE speaker

Comment: @D.Nelson Hm, Google News returns plenty of British results for [`"got a shock" UK`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22got+a+shock%22+UK&tbm=nws).

Comment: @D.Nelson  how about "receive a shock"?

Comment: "get a shock" is in itself fine to my NAmE ears, but is semantically odd here: I think "shocked" has undergone much more neutralization (tending towards merely "surprised") than "shock" has.

Comment: @LukeSawczak agreed,  Many parents would be *shocked* rather than *surprised* to see their children cleaning without being told.

Comment: @Andrew Ha, fair enough. But to me "get a shock" also implies some residual fear and trauma. One's hand jumps to one's heart and one half-falls backwards, hoping there's a sofa or a husband behind one. At least that's how they do it in the movies.

Comment: @LukeSawczak  good point, edited.

Comment: It's also common (at least in the US) to say "I *was **in*** shock" which refers more to the medical condition than anything about electricity.